# How to pass a type as prop in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next, npm-package

I have two packages one for common packages and the other for translations. I am transferring the type and translations from the translations package to my project and from my project to the common package. But to use the translations in the common package, I need the type too. Is there a way to pass the interface as a prop in react?

In simple words is there a way to pass interface/type as prop?

Comment: You cannot do pass a typescript type as a prop.  Probably you want a generic component where the <T> is the type that you want to pass.

Answer (score 1):

If ive understood the question correctly, you could create a separate file for your `type` declarations if they are going to be used in multiple places. Pseudo code sample below:

declarations.tsx:

```
export interface MyComponentProps {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2?: string;
    prop3?: string;
}
```

anotherFile.tsx

```
import { MyComponentProps } from './declarations'


...

export default function AnotherFile({prop1, prop2, prop3}: MyComponentProps){
...
}
```